# configuring AVAudioSession throws an error?

Tags: ios, swift, voip

Trying to set mode like this.But it throws an error as `The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 561017449.)`

```
do{
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setMode(AVAudioSession.Mode.voiceChat)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
            
        }
        catch{
            SwiftyBeaver.error("error in configureAudioSession \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
```

When I do voip call I am able to share the audio.When GSM call occurs I press "hold and accept".After ending GSM call I am not able to hear audio on our voip call. Why this is happening? Any hint will be helpful for me?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to print `error` instead of `error.localizedDescription`, it might give more useful info.

Comment: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=561017449 "(null)"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26759942/ios-audiounitinitialize-returns-error-code-561017449 ?

Comment: @AmuthaPriya - it means the audio category is alerady set in another app on your device level.